# develop old film, solve an old mystery

Tags: identification-request, mystery-novels

This just popped into my head.  I think I must have read it in the mid 1990s. I remember very little about it. I'm not even certain it was a novel, it could have been a short story. But I think it was probably a novel.

The protagonist finds some old, used but undeveloped rolls of photographic film. She* has them developed and what was on them led her to solve a mystery from years or decades past.

A minor twist at the end said that a forensic photographic expert told her that undeveloped film does not survive that long. After X years it is impossible to recover a picture. He couldn't explain how it survived. This was left as a mystery for the reader.

*I think the protagonist was female, but I'm not sure. Maybe written in the first person.

Edit - I am British, and read the book in England. It was probably a British author, and set in England.

Comment: Just a comment about undeveloped film. In 2015 a photographer purchased a vintage Leica with film in it. He carefully developed the film and found vacation photos from the 1950s. https://www.cnn.com/travel/article/mystery-photos-europe-1950s-travel-william-fagan/index.html

Comment: Not Julio Cortázar’s “Blow-Up”, I take it? Same idea, a photograph inadvertently capturing a murder, but too many differences between the question’s details and the short story. Protagonist is male, he takes the photograph himself rather than develop old film ...

Comment: No, definitely not.  Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Comment: This had nothing to do with Everest and mountain climbing?

Comment: I don't think so, but my memory is so vague. If you know of a fictional book involving developing old film and Everest, please share. It just might be the one.

Comment: @Pete I am referring to Summit by Harry Farthing: https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/20659687-summit